# Laravel random collection without an existing stored item in another collection relation

Tags: laravel

I would like to get a random item from a collection. if the random item already exist on my $candidat_exist collection i would like to random again in order to get a different item than the one stored in rencontre_officiel table

I was thinking something like this will work

```
        \\App\Licencies collection
        $candidat = $arbitres->random();

        $candidat_exist = \App\RencontreOfficiel::where('licencie_id' , $candidat->id)->where('rencontre_id' , $rencontre->id)->exists();

        while ($candidat_exist){
            $candidat = $arbitres->random();
        }

        dd($candidat);
```

my $candidat_exist is true so i would like to assign randomly another value

UPDATE :

```
$arbitres = Licencies::getArbitres();
```

and my function getArbitres() in the model is :

```
   public static function getArbitres(){

        $all_licences = Licencies::whereIn('activite_licencie_id' , [24,25,50,80])
            ->where('valid_licence_id' , 3)
            ->where('saison_id' , self::getSaison()->id)
            ->where('dispo' , 1)
            ->get();


        return $licences;
```

Here my model relation with Licencies model :

```
class RencontreOfficiel extends Model
{
    public function rencontre(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Rencontre' , 'rencontre_id');
    }

    public function licence(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Licencies' , 'licencie_id');
    }
}
```

Here my class Licencies with the relation divisions

```
public function divisions(){
        return $this->hasMany(LicenceDesignationDivision::class , 'licence_id');
    }
```

Here my $arbitres collection :

```
 $arbitres = $arbitres->reject(function ($arbitre) use ($rencontre) {
                return $arbitre->rencontreOfficiels->contains(function ($rencontreOfficiels) use ($rencontre) {
                    return $rencontreOfficiels->rencontre_id === $rencontre->id;
                });
            })->filter(function ($arbitre){

                return $arbitre->divisions->contains('categorie_compet_id', 1);

            })->filter(function($arbitre){

                return $arbitre->level >= 3;

            });
```

I need to check if i have an empty collection i need to change the categorie_compet_id value and if i still get nothing i need to change the level condition.

how could i achieve this propely  ?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve with that solution? Can you describe the original problem? Maybe you can filter the items before to avoid picking some items. Otherwise with your method you would end up making a database call for each check and that would make performances bad.

Comment: @mdexp thanks for your reply i would like to simply check in my table rencontre_officiel i already have the candidat retrieved randomly by the method, if it's the case i would like to pick up another candidat in order to don't get the same one. how could i do that without the database ?

Comment: How do you populate/retrieve the `$arbitres` collection? Maybe you can apply some filtering there to avoid database calls

Comment: Do you have any relationship between `Licencies` and `RecontreOfficiel` models? If so can you post both models?

Comment: @mdexp yes i have a belongsTo relation from RencontreOfficiel to Licencies

Comment: You can... Query `whereNotIn` to minimalize the database call... But for this, you need to implement new function in the model, or modify the existing one, or query in the controller...

Comment: could you make me a little exemple for doing this in the model ? @Smankusors

Answer (score 2):

Instead of getting all the `Licencies` records you could just narrow down your search by excluding all the models that already has a relationship with a `RecontreOfficiel` record.

I assume that each `Licencies` model can have many `RecontreOfficiel` models.

In your `Licencies` you should then have the following relationship:

```php
public function recontreOfficiels()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\RencontreOfficiel', 'licencie_id');
}
```

You could then filter the arbitres collection with:

```php
# Load arbitres
$arbitres = Licencies::getArbitres();
# Load relationship with RecontreOfficiel model
$arbitres->load('recontreOfficiels');

# Reject arbitres which any of its recontreOfficieles
# is already associated with the $recontre model
$arbitres = $arbitres->reject(function ($arbitre) use ($recontre) {
    return $arbitre->recontreOfficiels->contains(function($recontreOfficiele) use ($recontre) {
        return $recontreOfficiels->recontre_id === $recontre->id;
    });
});

# Then you should end up with a list of not associated arbitres that you can pluck from
$arbitres->random();
```

The best solution would be to use `whereDoesntHave` method when you get all the Arbitres, but that would require a major rework of your code.

---

#### Update

If you need to apply more conditions you can do so by chaining other methods after reject:

```php
$arbitres = $arbitres->reject(function ($arbitre) use ($recontre) {
    return $arbitre->recontreOfficiels->contains(function($recontreOfficiele) use ($recontre) {
        return $recontreOfficiels->recontre_id === $recontre->id;
    });
})->where('level', '>=', 5); // Here you take only arbitres with level greater than 5
```

You can see all the available methods in the [collections documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods)

Comment: is it possible to make something like this $new_candidat = $arbitres->where('id' , '!=' , $arbitres->id)->random() ?

Comment: when i get the random $arbitres i make some test and if it's not the right arbitre i would like to look for another one

Comment: What decides if the random value is the right one or not? The basic idea is to get in `$arbitres` collection only the valid ones, to avoid further checks after you have extracted the random one. If you need to make more checks you need to add these before calling `->random();`

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! When I get a random arbitre I need to check his  score level for exemple if the random arbitre have a low score level I need to check another one @mdexp

Comment: I can access the level like that $arbitre->level

Comment: Can I sort by level score the collection with your method ?

Comment: i updated the post i need to filter with another  relation, if i get an empty collection i need to look on another categorie_compet_id. how could i achieve this ?

Comment: same thing with the level, i didn't update the post with the where condition to the level, that's works but i need to make the same thing, if i get an empty collection with the level i need to update the level value in order to get something